# will_paginate + Infinite Scroll plugin - doesn't display "Loading" message

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, loader, will-paginate, infinite-scroll

I use `will_paginate` gem in combination with [Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/) and the mechanism is working pretty well.
The only exception is displaying info-message, when is loaded new content or when are already all data loaded - this message is not displayed.

Here is my pagination structure generated by `will_paginate` gem:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <span class="previous_page disabled">&#8592; Previous</span> 
  <em class="current">1</em> 
  <a rel="next" href="/articles?page=2">2</a> 
  <a href="/articles?page=3">3</a> 
  <a href="/articles?page=4">4</a> 
  <a class="next_page" rel="next" href="/articles?page=2">Next &#8594;</a>
</div>
```

And this is a setup of `Infinite Scroll plugin`:

```
  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.pagination',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '.pagination a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.box-item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
      }
    },

    function( newElements ) {
      var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
      });
    }
  );
```

Everything should be set up by the manual pages, but I don't know why, the info message and loader are not loaded...

Appreciate every help!

Comment: do you have the solution? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    nextSelector : '.pagination a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
```

use

```
    nextSelector : '.pagination a[rel="next"]', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
```

this may help you